# OS X shell script to connect to a known wifi AP without explicitly using a password

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, connection, shell-script

I'm trying to write a shell script that begins by connecting to a specific SSID (one that I've connected to before, a preferred network). The only way I can seem to do this via command-line is:

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 "MyAP" "PASSWORD"
```

How can I connect to "MyAP" network without storing the password insecurely in the shell script?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a great tutorial by Allan Odgaard](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/) on the texmate blog which describes how to use the keychain utility from the command line in order to retrieve a password (amongst other things).  I suggest reading it through, as well as the corresponding comments.  You can create a function to be generically used, such as

```
#!/bin/bash

get_pw () { 
    security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga "$1" \
    | ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: "(.*)"$/'
}

pass=$(get_pw $1)
echo $pass
```

In order for this to be accomplished programmatically, without user confirmation, you will need to grant the `security` binary (in my installation of 10.11.2 it is located at `/usr/bin/security`) access to the specific password.  This can be done in either of two ways:

1. by executing the following from a terminal

   ```
   security add-generic-password -a "account name" -s "service name" -T "/usr/bin/security" -U
   ```

   as described by davidacland in his [JAMFNation response](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=14415). ***Note***: I have not been able to reproduce this with an existing keychain item (as davidacland's response suggests is possible).

-**or**-

2. using the **Keychain Access.app** GUI to manually add `security` to the Keychain item's Access Control list:
   Keychain Access GUI -> double-click on Keychain Item -> Access Control

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's the first available preferred network (Network Preferences, Advanced, "Remember networks this computer has joined" is checked) and you don't have "Require administrator authorization to: - Turn Wi-Fi on or off" checked  you can use

`networksetup -setairportpower en0 off` followed by by
`networksetup -setairportpower en0 on` and it will connect to the first available preferred network without requiring a password (tried on OS X 10.9.4).

If you execute `networksetup -help` the last output line is

> > Any command that takes a password, will accept - to indicate the password should be read from stdin.